# How to get methods list in visual studio akin to Netbeans?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, methods, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans for a bit now and found that whenever I typed "CLASS." it lists out every method/properties of such class and found it extremely helpful for coding.

But when I went over to visual studio code to do some C# coding for Unity, I found that I severely miss that feature. I was wondering how can I have the same method list from Netbeans over to VSCode, specifically for Unity Library?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Please don't use the `visual-studio` for VSCode. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Have you considered using Visual Studio Community Edition, rather than VS Code?